# Meteor.call callback not executing

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback, call

```
//on client side
Meteor.call('myFunction', function(err, result) {
   alert("entered the callback function");
   });


//on server side
Meteor.methods({
   myFunction: function() {
       return 0;
   }
})
```

My problem is that the alert is never called. Regardless of what myFunction is, what it returns and when it returns, the alert in the callback function should be executed, but that never happens.

Any idea of what could be happening here and a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for my case.

`Meteor.call` on the client side was inside an *submit* event, because I was doing a form.
Changing the event type to *click*, made the `Meteor.call` work fine.

I still don't know the reason for this, but it solved my problem.

Comment: Same issue, but switching to `click` didn't helped me. The callback still isn't  called